# Regex to fix malformed vector

Tags: javascript, regex, figma-api

I have an API that is returning the following, malformed string:

`M0 0L1.33333 0L1.33333 4L4.44089e-16 4L0 0Z`

It should look like this:

`M 0 0 L 1.33333 0 L 1.33333 4 L 4.44089e-16 4 L 0 0 Z`

How could I write a regex that would select any letter that has a number next to it, preceding or following?

Here are the strings again, next to each other:

`M0 0L1.33333 0L1.33333 4L4.44089e-16 4L0 0Z` <-incorrect

`M 0 0 L 1.33333 0 L 1.33333 4 L 4.44089e-16 4 L 0 0 Z` <-correct

Thanks!

A little background: this is a vector returned by the [Figma API](https://www.figma.com/developers/api) and I don't know why it's formatted like that.

Answer (score -1):

something like this should work: `/[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z]/g`

https://regexr.com/ really helps with testing out regexes.

here's a link to the one i've been testing on:
https://regexr.com/65vu7

Comment: This is close, but it selects the letter _and_ the number next door.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this regex here [regexr.com/65vvt](http://regexr.com/65vvt)

```
([A-Z])\d|\d([A-Z])
```

And then check for capture group 1 or 2. That will match all the capital letters of your incorrect example string but none of your correct string.